# Button is not touchable and Action is Not calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7

I have a main view-->Subview-->ScrollView

I am displaying data in scrollview dynamically. Everything is good, but the problem is I am not able to tap on that button.

I have a taken a button through drag and drop.

And I gave a Frame to that button according to scrollview position.

```
objLabel.frame = CGRectMake(2,0,scrlMoreDetail.frame.size.width-4,setY);

[objLabel release];

scrlMoreDetail.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrlMoreDetail.frame.size.width, setY);

setY = setY + 10;

scrlMoreDetail.frame = CGRectMake(scrlMoreDetail.frame.origin.x, scrlMoreDetail.frame.origin.y, scrlMoreDetail.frame.size.width, setY + 10);

btnMoreClose.frame = CGRectMake(btnMoreClose.frame.origin.x, scrlMoreDetail.frame.origin.y +scrlMoreDetail.frame.size.height, btnMoreClose.frame.size.width, btnMoreClose.frame.size.height);

subviewMoreDetail.frame =CGRectMake(subviewMoreDetail.frame.origin.x, subviewMoreDetail.frame.origin.y, subviewMoreDetail.frame.size.width,btnMoreClose.frame.origin.y + btnMoreClose.frame.size.height );
```

Comment: :- Have you added action to your button?..

Comment: but your code is not related to your button

Comment: Yes ,i have added action- (IBAction)doBtnMoreClose:(UIButton *)sender
{
}

Comment: karthik,actually btnMoreclose is the Button

Comment: How you connected the IBAction??
Was it through storyboard or done programmatically ?

Comment: The IBAction is Connected through XIB.

Comment: try this yourscrollview bringsubviewtofront: btnMoreClose

Comment: yes.eventhough i tried your logic also kathik,still not working.

Comment: if you are displaying data dynamically on scrollview, how can you connect ibaction to the xib ?

Answer (score 0):

Check ur button have user interaction Enabled Yes or Not.
That also there means, once 
add like this.

```
[self.scrollview_name addsubview:Btn_Name];
```